# Slick carrusel arrows not showing

Tags: slick.js, arrows

I'm hosting my company's store with shopify http://kids.sevenly.org, the slick carrusel looks awesome but i can't get the arrows to show. Can anyone help me, I've tried everything, it's driving me insane.

```js
/*
     _ _      _       _
 ___| (_) ___| | __  (_)___
/ __| | |/ __| |/ /  | / __|
\__ \ | | (__|   < _ | \__ \
|___/_|_|\___|_|\_(_)/ |___/

 */
/* global window, document, define, jQuery, setInterval, clearInterval */
(function(factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }

}(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var Slick = window.Slick || {};

    Slick = (function() {

        var instanceUid = 0;

        function Slick(element, settings) {

            var _ = this, dataSettings;

            _.defaults = {
                accessibility: true,
                adaptiveHeight: false,
                appendArrows: $(element),
                appendDots: $(element),
                arrows: true,
                asNavFor: null,
                prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">Previous</button>',
                nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>',
                autoplay: false,
                autoplaySpeed: 3000,
                centerMode: false,
                centerPadding: '50px',
                cssEase: 'ease',
                customPaging: function(slider, i) {
                    return '<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">' + (i + 1) + '</button>';
                },
                dots: false,
                dotsClass: 'slick-dots',
                draggable: true,
                easing: 'linear',
                edgeFriction: 0.35,
                fade: false,
                focusOnSelect: false,
                infinite: true,
                initialSlide: 0,
                lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
                mobileFirst: false,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                pauseOnDotsHover: false,
                respondTo: 'window',
                responsive: null,
                rows: 1,
                rtl: false,
                slide: '',
                slidesPerRow: 1,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                speed: 500,
                swipe: true,
                swipeToSlide: false,
                touchMove: true,
                touchThreshold: 5,
                useCSS: true,
                variableWidth: false,
                vertical: false,
                verticalSwiping: false,
                waitForAnimate: true,
                zIndex: 1000
            };

            _.initials = {
                animating: false,
                dragging: false,
                autoPlayTimer: null,
                currentDirection: 0,
                currentLeft: null,
                currentSlide: 0,
                direction: 1,
                $dots: null,
                listWidth: null,
                listHeight: null,
                loadIndex: 0,
                $nextArrow: null,
                $prevArrow: null,
                slideCount: null,
                slideWidth: null,
                $slideTrack: null,
                $slides: null,
                sliding: false,
                slideOffset: 0,
                swipeLeft: null,
                $list: null,
                touchObject: {},
                transformsEnabled: false,
                unslicked: false
            };

            $.extend(_, _.initials);

            _.activeBreakpoint = null;
            _.animType = null;
            _.animProp = null;
            _.breakpoints = [];
            _.breakpointSettings = [];
            _.cssTransitions = false;
            _.hidden = 'hidden';
            _.paused = false;
            _.positionProp = null;
            _.respondTo = null;
            _.rowCount = 1;
            _.shouldClick = true;
            _.$slider = $(element);
            _.$slidesCache = null;
            _.transformType = null;
            _.transitionType = null;
            _.visibilityChange = 'visibilitychange';
            _.windowWidth = 0;
            _.windowTimer = null;

            dataSettings = $(element).data('slick') || {};

            _.options = $.extend({}, _.defaults, dataSettings, settings);

            _.currentSlide = _.options.initialSlide;

            _.originalSettings = _.options;

            if (typeof document.mozHidden !== 'undefined') {
                _.hidden = 'mozHidden';
                _.visibilityChange = 'mozvisibilitychange';
            } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
                _.hidden = 'webkitHidden';
                _.visibilityChange = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
            }
```

```css
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider CSS-theme */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('./ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
/* Arrows */

.slick-prev:after {
  content: ">";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.slick-next:before {
  content: "<"
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}

<!--.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before{
    color: white;-->

    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: white;
    border: white;
    outline: white;
    background: white;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus
{
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before
{
    opacity: .25;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;

    opacity: .75;
    color: white;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev
{
    left: 40px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev
{
    right: 40px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}

.slick-next
{
    right: 40px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next
{
    right: auto;
    left: 40px;
}
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}

/* Dots */
.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;
    color: black;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}
```

```css
/* Slider SLICK.CSS */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: block;
}
```

```js
<!--Slick Initialize -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fade').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 2000,
      fade: true,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      prevArrow: true,
      nextArrow: true,
      lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
      autoplay: true
    });

    $('.lazy').slick({
      lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: I cut the bottom on the first JS code that wasn't related to the arrows so I could meet the 30000 character requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your slick configuration is incorrect. You have `prevArrow` and `nextArrow` set to true when you should just have `arrows` set to true. `prevArrow` and `nextArrow` are used to customize the HTML for the previous and next arrows.

You should use the following instead:

```
<!--Slick Initialize -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fade').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 2000,
      fade: true,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      arrows: true,
      lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
      autoplay: true
    });

    $('.lazy').slick({
      lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here's the documentation for future reference: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thank you for your help, it didn't work though :-/ still no arrows

Comment: I just looked through your code, and assuming that the Slick initialize code is in your compiled.js file, it doesn't look like your latest updates (to add the arrows: true option) got compiled and/or pushed to the server.